# Trouble using express.session with https

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, https, express

I have to use authentication and then create a session for this i have a HTTPS static website running on expressjs

Code :

**app.js:**

```
//created the https server

var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/svgtest1');

// This line is from the Node.js HTTPS documentation.
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('privatekey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem')
};

// Create a service (the app object is just a callback).
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({cookie: { httpOnly: false , maxAge: 24*60*60*1000}, secret: '1234567890QWERT'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());


// middle ware to check auth
function checkAuth(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.session.user_id) {
    res.send('You are not authorized to view this page');
  } else {
    next();
  }
}


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('First page called');
  res.redirect('xyz.html');
  res.end();
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  console.log('login called');
  var usrfield = req.body.usrfield;
  var passfield = req.body.passfield;

    // Play with the username and password

    if (usrfield == 'xxx' && passfield == 'xxx') {
    req.session.user_id = '123';
    res.redirect('abc.html');
  } else {
    res.send('Bad user/pass');
  }


    console.log(usrfield);
    console.log(passfield);
    res.end();
});


// Create an HTTPS service.
https.createServer(options, app).listen(8888);
```

1. When I visits `https://localhost:8888` it continuously loads the page and does not redirect to xyz.html where i have to enter the credentials to authenticate the user ?
2. When I comment out

   app.use(express.session({cookie: { httpOnly: false , maxAge: 24*60*60*1000}, secret: '1234567890QWERT'}));

Then the page loads correctly but when i post the form to /login then it says req.session cannot be written. For this i know because i have comment out the express.session, but the strange thing is that connect.sid cookie is created. Why ?

I am confused regarding question 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your example, and it works for me.  Are you sure you're using the `https` protocol in the browser?  By default, a browser will try to connect with HTTP protocol *unless* you redirect to HTTP.  With your set, navigating to this URL will just spin:

```
http://localhost:8888
```

However, if you navigate to this URL:

```
https://localhost:8888
```

It will work as expected.  Most servers that use HTTPS automatically redirect to an HTTPS connection if the user came in over HTTP, but you *still* have to have two servers: one accepting HTTP request, and the other accepting HTTPS requests.  For example, you could do this:

```
// create an HTTPS service
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);

// create HTTP service to redirect to HTTPS
http.createServer(express().use(function(req,res){
    res.redirect('https://localhost:443' + req.url);
})).listen(8888);
```

Note that if you use ports below 1024 (such as 443, which is common for HTTPS), you'll probably have to have elevated privileges depending on your server set up.  In OSX/Linux, you would just do `sudo node app.js`.  Of course you don't have to run on port 443: you could have your HTTPS server run on 8887 and your HTTP redirect server run on 8888.

Comment: Yeah I am sure and used  "https://localhost:8888" but the browser just spins and also the console of server sends first page called and also if i place console.log(redirected); The server console also says redirected but my webpage is still loading and the webpage is on the same page no redirection. only if I comment out app.use(express.session({cookie: { httpOnly: false , maxAge: 24*60*60*1000}, secret: '1234567890QWERT'}));
then it works but then offcourse req.session not works but then navigation is ok.

Comment: Does express.session needs any thing prerequisite which i may not using or its not working for https?. I have a static website in public and its html and javascript

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what's going on, because your code works for me exactly as written.  What I did was cut your code from this question, paste it into a file called `app.js`.  Then I created a `package.json` file, and added Express to it (`npm install express --save`), then ran `npm install` so the dependency would be available.  I then generated a private key and certificate using `openssl`, named them to match your source, and ran it.

Comment: Maybe you need to update Express?  What version of Express is specified in your `package.json` file?  What version of Express is actually installed?  (You can check `node_modules/express/package.json` to determine that.)

Comment: I'm using Express 3.4.7

Comment: I have changed the app.use(express.session({cookie: { httpOnly: false , maxAge: 24*60*60*1000}, secret: '1234567890QWERT'})); to app.use(express.session({cookie: {  path: '/public/',httpOnly: false , maxAge: 24*60*60*1000}, secret: '1234567890QWERT'})); means included my path /public not it redirects but another problem arrives that req.session is showing undefined. Means i cannot use req.session.usr_id

Comment: The problem is solved by changing the browser from mozilla to chrome but i dont know why :D
Also this answer also helped http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093787/req-session-undefined-and-req-session-user-id-not-working

Comment: Hm, weird.  I'll have to try it with Firefox; I'm curious as to why that would make a difference.  It does support my suspicion that something funky is going on with the browser's choice of HTTP/HTTPS.  Maybe you have to go through some hoops to make Firefox use HTTPS over a port that isn't 443, I don't know....