# req.session undefined and req.session.user_id not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies, express

I am using Express and node for the session management with https. I want to create a session using express so that authentication and the session is made before the redirection to the static files in the public folder. Previously i was having a problem [Trouble using express.session with https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051252/trouble-using-express-session-with-https)
But it was solved by including path in the express.session as /public but now my req.session is showing as undefined but in the browser there is connect.sid cookie present

The app.js is :

```
var express = require('express')TypeError: Cannot set property 'user_id' of undefined at /opt/expressjs/app.js:59:24 at callbacks;
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/svgtest1');
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('privatekey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem')
};

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({cookie: {  path: '/public/',httpOnly: false , maxAge: 24*60*60*1000}, secret: '1234567890QWERT'}));

//middle ware to check auth
function checkAuth(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.session.user_id) {
    res.send('You are not authorized to view this page');
  } else {
    next();
  }
}


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('First page called');
  res.redirect('loginform.html');
  console.log('redirected');
  res.end();
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  console.log('login called');
  var usrfield = req.body.usrfield;
  var passfield = req.body.passfield;

    console.log(req.session);


// Play with the username and password

        if (usrfield == 'kk' && passfield == '123') {
             req.session.user_id = 'xyz';
        res.redirect('svg-edit.html');
      } else {
        res.send('Bad user/pass');
      }


        console.log(usrfield);
        console.log(passfield);
        res.end();
    });
```

Client Side :

```
<html>

<style media="screen" type="text/css">
@import url("css/loginform_styles.css");
 </style>

    <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="annotationTools/js/md5.js" ></script>
            <script>

                function validateForm()
                {
                    var usrnamefield=document.forms["loginform"]["usrfield"].value;
                    var passwrdfield=document.forms["loginform"]["passfield"].value;

                    if ((usrnamefield==null || usrnamefield=="")||(passwrdfield==null || passwrdfield==""))
                      {
                        document.getElementById('valueerrorlayer').innerHTML ='Username or password field is empty';
                        //document.forms["loginform"]["errorshow"].innerHtml = 'username or password empty';
                      return false;
                      }
                    else return true;
                }
            </script>

    </head>

    <body>


    <form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="https://localhost:8888/login" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        <div id = "content" align = "center">

            <p align="center"><font size="7">LabelMe Dev</font></p> 
            <br />
            <br />

            <label> Please Enter the <b><i>Username</i></b></label>
            <br />
            <br />

            <input type="text"  name = "usrfield" id = "usrfield" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnSearch').click()"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />

            <label> Please Enter the <b><i>Password</i></b></label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="password"  name = "passfield" id = "passfield" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnSearch').click()"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />

            <i><p id='valueerrorlayer' style="color:red;"> </p></i>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
    </form>     
    </body>





</html>
```

**The problem** is that `console.log(req.session);` gives undefined so the `req.session.user_id = 'xyz';` also not works and error `'TypeError: Cannot set property 'user_id' of undefined at /opt/expressjs/app.js:59:24 at callbacks'` comes.
I have gone through many questions but was not able to figure out.

My website is static and all the *.html locates in the public directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The session middleware checks if an incoming request matches the cookie path; if not, it doesn't bother continuing (and `req.session` won't even be created). In your situation, your cookie path is set to `/public/`, which doesn't match the request path `/login`.

I think you'd want to configure the session middleware cookie to use `/` as a path:

```
app.use(express.session({
  cookie: {
    path    : '/',
    httpOnly: false,
    maxAge  : 24*60*60*1000
  },
  secret: '1234567890QWERT'
}));
```

Comment: But when i convert the path to '/' the problem of *Trouble using express.session with https* occurs which means when i goto https://localhost:8888 to get the 'loginform.html' the browser continously loads and no result prompts.

Comment: @Zeeshan so what is the exact URL that you enter in your browser to get that HTML file?

Comment: When I use :.
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.session({
cookie: {
 path    : '/',
    httpOnly: false,
    maxAge  : 24*60*60*1000
  },
  secret: '1234567890QWERT'
}));
then the routing problem is solved means i am redirected but on post this error occurs TypeError: Cannot set property 'user_id' of undefined at /opt/expressjs/app.js:72:24 at callbacks

Comment: @Zeeshan that works because you're circumventing the `express.session` middleware like that. I have no idea why that specifically is causing the problem, because it works for me and also for the people answering your previous question.

Comment: Ok for using express.session is any prerequisits required to install or its buildin in express 3.4.7 and also the cookie connect.sid is created with some value

Comment: @Zeeshan no prerequisites are required for it to work. By the way, how are you getting an error on line 72 of `app.js` while you're only posting 58 lines of code in your question? Are you **absolutely sure** that you're not using *any* other code that might be causing a conflict or an error?

Comment: no i am sure it was when i have created a test route in the line 72 and there i was checking.
the position o app.use(app.router); also matters if i put before session the express.session is undefined but redirection works good and if i put it after app.use(session) then my page does not redirects

Comment: I dont know how the error is fixed by changing the browser from mozilla to chrome but it works :D

Comment: I have the similar problem. It doesn't work in Chrome but Safari is ok.