# Node.js req.session variable undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

main.js (only the relevant parts)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('express')(),
    expressSession = require('express-session'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

// Access Middleware
var connect = require('connect');
var http = require('http');
var session = require('express-session');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'SECKEY',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.post('/process_post', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
    // Prepare output in JSON format
    var response = {
        first_name:req.body.first_name,
        last_name:req.body.last_name
    };
    console.log(response);


    var post = req.body;
    if(post.first_name === 'u' && post.last_name === 'p') {
        res.session.user_id = 3;
        res.redirect('/home');
    } else {
        res.send('INVALID');
    }

    res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

This is the error I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'user_id' of undefined
   at D:\Users\Winston\Code\NodeJS Projects\Sample\main.js:43:29
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Users\Winston\Code\NodeJS Projects\Sample\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at next (D:\Users\Winston\Code\NodeJS Projects\Sample\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
   at D:\Users\Winston\Code\NodeJS Projects\Sample\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:5
   at invokeCallback (D:\Users\Winston\Code\NodeJS Projects\Sample\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:262:16)
   at done (D:\Users\Winston\Code\NodeJS Projects\Sample\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:251:7)
   at IncomingMessage.onEnd (D:\Users\Winston\Code\NodeJS Projects\Sample\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:308:7)
   at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:104:17)
   at _stream_readable.js:908:16
   at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

req.session isn't working, but I think I defined everything. I have installed connect and express-session middleware. How can I debug problems like this in the future?

EDIT 1: Print out req.session

```
{ cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true } }
{ first_name: 'u', last_name: 'p' }
{ cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true } }
```

Comment: check this SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093787/req-session-undefined-and-req-session-user-id-not-working

Comment: I have implemented that solution. `Error: Most middleware (like session) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Pl
ease see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.` It cries at express.session. I believe I have already installed express-session and put it in package.json? Could this be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `res.session` not `req.session`

Comment: Thanks for responding, I fixed it but the exact same error persists.

Answer (score 1):

You change your code below:

```
res.session.user_id = 3;
```

to

```
req.session.user_id = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I fixed it but the exact same error persists

Comment: Can you show req.session result and your error for me?

Comment: you can check "req.session.identify" variable information? If it exist, you can see user_id of you in this object.

Comment: It would appear that req.session.identify is undefined, but there is more info

Comment: I read about "EDIT 1: Print out req.session" of you. req.session information result is fully?